# Is there any way of updating the CidrIp value of AWS security group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Is there any way of updating the CidrIp value of AWS security group? I have used AuthorizeSecurityGroupEgress to add the CIDR ip but need something which will only update the existing IP?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you're attempting to do.

Comment: We just need to update the IP in security groups everytime for existing user.